# TypeScript generics - Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am developing a function that takes in an array of objects and resamples the array based on a property of the objects.  (More theory on that in my question [resampling an array of objects](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40065/resampling-an-array-of-objects?noredirect=1#comment77619_40065).  In typescript, the function starts like this:

```
export function resample<T>(
    originalArray: Array<T>,
    sortKey: keyof T,
    samplingInterval: number
): Array<T> {

  const array = [...originalArray];
  let queuedItem = array.shift();
  let t0: number = queuedItem[sortKey]; // <-------- problem here

  // ... more code

}
```

When trying to type `t0` as a number, I get the error:

`Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'number'`

### [TypeScript playground demonstrating the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVysAZwEMBbMAG2AB4AVAPgAoBYAKAEhpMBzTFI8gIJQoRAJ4AuOEJGjadADSs2BaDADSwCXADWmiAjg1F7YmXK8uASRQxgUAG79JKJCQBGd1gEpJ0sXLgAb1ZWODC4NBwCeCJhMTgAXjgAbQA6dM4ePkE40QBdAG4QlnCIqPh8AiRyGF9cgKTkwuLSyngARyRgLoATS1sSRLhYmVSCAAtMBBgGLyKS8La4GAAGZ1cPKCHO7uA+gYBCZJVYDXyCuAB6S7gqAFoHx4e4MCgIN0pB8btgFqub9KpOAkaDAMo9X4sULhfAwJBQXCVaoweasAC+QA)

Without explicitly defining the type, `t0` is typed as `T[keyof T]`.  Which makes sense.  But later in the code, I do some simple math with `t0`, and I need it ot be treated as a number.

Why can `T[string]` not be assignable to a number type?  We have no information thus far about what's in `T`, why does typescript prohibit that `T[keyof T]` from being a number?

Can I better type this function, and `T`?  It must be that `T` has at least one property whose value is a number, but whose key could be any string, and when being used in the `resample` function, `sortKey` is any property of `T` whose value is a number?

Comment: Since T can be anything, so can `queuedItem[sortKey]`, so it can be NOT a number.

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wRJg7w) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not please [edit] the example code to demonstrate unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: @jcalz your code seems to work, but I'm not sure I understand it.  Can you post an answer with explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion here is to make the `resample` function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) both in `T`, the type of the elements of `originalArray`, and in `K`, the type of `sortKey`:

```
function resample<T extends Record<K, number>, K extends keyof T>(
    originalArray: Array<T>,
    sortKey: K,
) { 
    const array = [...originalArray];
    let queuedItem = array.shift();
    let t0: number = queuedItem![sortKey]; // no error now
}
```

By [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` to extend `keyof T` we are requiring that `sortKey` be one of the keys of the elements of `obj`, and by constraining `T` to extend `Record<K, number>` (using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)) we are requiring that the elements of `obj` have a `number` value at the key `K`.

Then you should be able to call `resample()` and see that it works for valid calls and reports an error for invalid calls:

```
resample([{ a: 123, b: "hello" }], "a"); // okay
resample([{ a: 123, b: "hello" }], "b"); // error!
// ---------------> ~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

---

Technically you don't need to do both constraints; it is sufficient to have just `K`:

```
function resample<K extends PropertyKey>(
    originalArray: Array<Record<K, number>>,
    sortKey: K,
) { /* same impl */ }
```

But then you run into [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) where the compiler complains when *object literals* have properties that it wasn't expecting:

```
resample([{ a: 123, b: "hello" }], "a"); // error?!
// ---------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
//  Object literal may only specify known properties,
//  and 'b' does not exist in type 'Record<"a", number>'
```

You don't want this behavior because it really isn't indicative of an error that your object has more keys than `"a"`.  This can be worked around or avoided by not calling `resample()` with object literal arguments, by initializing a variable with the object literal and then calling `resample()` with that variable:

```
const differentVariable = { a: 123, b: "hello" };
resample([differentVariable], "a"); // okay
```

But one way to turn off such checking is to make the elements of `obj` of a generic type `T extends Record<K, number>` instead of the specific type `Record<K, number>`.  Which is what I suggest above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlArgcw9ALgSwHtgkBvAWAChKkakAzNYefIpAJ2nBgBsIAeACpIIADxwRgAEyhIAShHgE2kvgGkANEmBowAIwhsAfJtXCxE6UgDWEAJ4E6SAYYAU1Wh6V4MeUNwCCbGwgtgBcSIHBtoLG7h40UEo4qnbhGnFIAJSkGR6KwFA4SCBBIUgAvEgA2gB0dV4+fpEhALoA3Lm0vEUAjmgQ-ZIAkuJgFcWltjVQABZ4dDgumR0U8V0QRTgADOHaegbjfQMQw6MAhFWJbMl27RkAvpQZHFBcvC5VJMXhAIwATABmTS6cIAIhmEG43AIoKQ9xamlBIFByyQAHo0UgCFYQs9OGAeBAPl8QL9AcCwRCoTC4QikKDdCi2ujMQY2EozhkMUgALR8-kCwWGJAAPy5mIEthgyAA5IU2L4MDKkHgZMACEUQFAoN5QLpeEgcARDVLZXt9GwZTVKI8qBRQJBYAhkAIFDNgHh4CAobZ0HQ6J68BIiuQ7R4GEwWMQXm9+KZROIpDIAArs6XXWwpWyuTo0Bq+b3NMIRSZ8eSKZRqTTmgyGWKrNZIK43YvpBs0bKhxtIfKFCZRca1eoKxqFyZ3dvxbpII6DEYQMaVEpRaZzBZLFbd6fbXY6C2Hfpz86XJJZiceW1414E96fb5If5ApAg+lU6Gw+GI5Go7lspQAfk5SduUFUCBWFEVIKg6DxRoAB5XQACsFCKbg8HEYJuCQMAyiIbhbCbaV4HmAirHVAB3YgYDTAx8GgdRYOKKQkBlXRlUkAhoC0DUzFVIpfBNaUWPLJQVCRUFqz3WsZSeSdeyKSR5joAxgwANRKPAQH1ZBKhJMknxfcFIXfOFN1oGMbyJKpFP9FTgBwdSFS03g6XEn9MWxXEw3M-FCWJe9HwpV9jJpT96UZdzhCCDlYLAuKINgyUhLlHAFWAJUVTVHitR1DA9QNI1BLNKTLWtCh7iAA)

Comment: Great point to extend the record!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are missing constraints on the type T, that's why TS has no idea what type will be given after: `queuedItem[sortKey]`

To fix this, simply add constraint like this:

Pay attention to the `extends`:

```js
export function resample<T extends {[key in keyof T] : number}>(originalArray: T[], sortKey: keyof T,   samplingInterval: number): Array<T> {

    const array = [...originalArray];

    const result: Array<T> = [];

    let queuedItem = array.shift();
    let t0:number = queuedItem![sortKey]; // <-------- no problem here

  // ... more code

    return result;

}
```

Comment: This should force ALL properties on T to be of type number?

Comment: In the original question not every key has a number value, I believe.

Comment: Yes exactly, I don't want *every* property to have to be a number, just at least one of them